# DOMDocument, getNamedItem and nodeValue

Tags: php, xml, domdocument

I get     `Fatal error: Call to undefined method DOMElement::getNamedItem()` and I'm not sure why. There's definitely something I dont understand with this DOMdocument thing. Here's my code:

```
// load content of db
$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0');
$dom->load($file);

// make domnodelist with girls
$girls = $dom->getElementsByTagName('girl');

foreach($girls as $girl)
{
    $username = $girl->getNamedItem('username');
    echo $username->nodeValue;
}
```

Here's my xml:

```
<root>
  <girl username="xxxx" id="2012111003051009">
    <url>xxxx</url>
    <replied>false</replied>
    <thumbnail>dbs/db-thumbnails/xxxx.jpeg</thumbnail>
    <blacklisted>false</blacklisted>
    </girl>
</root>
```

Answer (score 1):

`username` is an attribute of the `DOMElement` $girl. So what you need to use is `getAttribute`.

```
foreach($girls as $girl)
{
    $username = $girl->getAttribute('username');
    // or if using getNamedItem 
    // $username = $girl->attributes->getNamedItem ('username')->nodeValue
    echo $username;
}
```

Comment: I used

    `foreach($girls as $girl)
    {
        $username = $girl->getAttribute('girl');
        print_r($username);
    }`

and it didnt print anything in my browser

Comment: It's `getAttribute('username')`

Comment: thanks it worked, I'm getting another error using the same xml file and DOMDocument: 
    `$username = xxxx; $girl = $dom->getAttributeNode($username);`

Comment: `getAttributeNode` will return the named attribute of an element. So inside the foreach try `$username_attribute = $girl->getAttributeNode('username');`

Comment: My goal is to do this `$blacklisted = $girl->getElementsByTagName('blacklisted');
    $blacklisted = $blacklisted->item(0);`, how can I get `$girl` to be a specific element with attribute `username=$username`?